# Unable to install gnome extensions due to 'undefined' error in extensions.gnome.org on firefox

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am unable to install gnome-extensions since last reboot.

[image: **Screenshot of error message**]

I tried resetting gnome using `gnome-tweaks` and reinstalling `chrome-gnome-shell`, `gnome-shell-extension` and, '*GNOME Shell integration*' plugin for Firefox. I am using Ubuntu version 18.04.2 and kernel `5.2.5-050205-generic`.

Comment: Try booting to the standard 18.04.2 kernel and see if things improve. Report back.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what did you do, but I backup up all my extensions (copied the `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` folder), reinstall OS (Fedora 30), removed `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` folder, created a symlink to the backed up folder (link being in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Then I’ve got the error.

I believe that the Firefox extension checks if `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extesions` is a folder, but a symlink is not a folder (not even when it links to a folder), therefore a variable in the Firefox extension is left undefined.

#### Solution

The folder `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` must be a folder, not a symlink. In my case, I symlink `~/.local/share/gnome-shell` and it works again. If you don’t want/need to use a symlink, use regular folders and the issue disappears.

Comment: In my case, it was some issue with OpenSSL. It started working after I updated OpenSSL to the latest version. ( I was preventing OpenSSL from updating due to unrelated reasons).